# GetItemLinqQueryable method Cosmos DB SDK v3 are chatty too much with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

At first, I using the `GetItemLinqQueryable` method to query my records without the `ToFeedIterator` extension.

Here is the dependency tracking on Application Insights, too many requests come into Cosmos DB at the same time.
As a result, when the system running at peak time, it uses a large provisioned throughput and causes a bottleneck at Cosmos DB

[image: Log image]

After that, I used `ToFeedIterator` to make the function asynchronous as a recommendation.
The code sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemlinqqueryable?view=azure-dotnet

Then, we can reduce 5 times the amount of request to Cosmos Db at the peak time
But I still got 2 requests to Cosmos DB as the Application Insights refer.
[image]

As the SDK v2, I only got  1 request to Cosmos DB, that help to save a lot RU to Cosmos DB

Does anyone know why we need to send many requests to Cosmos DB when using SKD v3?

Comment: Please include your code for the query for both v2 and v3?

Comment: @NoahStahl I just use the built-in function
GetItemLinqQueryable(x => x.Myproperty == "value")
Anw, I attached the code sample

Comment: Any difference using GetItemQueryIterator instead of LINQ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.container.getitemqueryiterator?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: @NoahStahl, same thing with GetItemLinqQueryable(2 query documents)